# Alguien sabe si se puede cambiar retrofit2 por otro nombre como hero

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-sqlite

tengo estas dos lineas de codigo:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

pero tengo una duda se puede cambiar retrofit2 por otra variable que sea por ejemplo hero:

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.hero:retrofit:2.5.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.hero:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

y tambien si se puede como se realiza ?

Comment: Si defines una constante? ejmplo: def HERO = "hero", y haces esto entre comillas dobles:  implementation "com.squareup.HERO:converter-gson:2.5.0"

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no son lineas de código, son dependencias que definen la inclusión de otras library (módulos) a tu proyecto, si deseas cambiar por ejemplo de

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
```

hacia:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.hero:retrofit:2.5.0'
```

debes asegurar que esta dependencia en verdad exista, de lo contrario no es valido agregar una dependencia que no se pueda resolver en tu proyecto Android.

Para conocer si existe determinado repositorio te sugiero revisar en :

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup

en este caso el repositorio que deseas cambiar [com.squareup.hero](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup), en realidad no existe, puedes ver la lista de repositorios disponibles para el paquete [com.squareup](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup).